SwiftUI NavigationLink Freezes when View contains `dismiss` Environment value
When tapping a NavigationLink within a NavigationStack, my app freezes and is unrecoverable:
import SwiftUI

@main
struct State_BugApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationSplitView {
                List {
                    Section {
                        Text("Home")
                    }
                }.listStyle(.insetGrouped)
            } detail: {
                NavigationStack {
                    MainView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @State var action: String = "Open child"
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            NavigationLink {
                listDestination()
            } label: {
                Text(action)
            }
        }
    }

    @ViewBuilder func listDestination() -> some View {
        ChildView(action: { value in foo() })
    }

    func foo() {
        self.action = "Updated action"
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ChildViewModel = ChildViewModel()
    var action: (String) -> Void

    init(action: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
        self.action = action
    }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Text")
        }
    }
}

class ChildViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var title: String = "Child"
}

If you remove the @Environment(\.dismiss) it works, however I then can’t dismiss my view at all….
The issue stems from the fact that the dismiss value is not equatable and is therefore causing a cycle, because the view redraws endlessly when tapping the NavigationLink. It’s documented here https://hachyderm.io/@teissler/112533860374716961 and here https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/720096#:~:text=This%20is%20a%20problem%20if,to%20construct%20the%20presented%20view. but I can’t figure out how you’d resolve the requirement to use dismiss.

Where are you calling dismiss() though?

In the MRP I am not calling it, in my real code I am. The MRP provided is purely to illustrate the minimum required code to reproduce the issue. With or without calling dismiss() the issue exists.

Do you mean you want to programmatically go back to the sidebar view? Is that why you used dismiss?

NavigationSplitView Has a ton of issues when mixed with NavugationStack. If you can try switching to the new TabView that has a sidebar

@loremipsum that is only available for iOS 18, I'm targeting iOS 16

@Sweeper no, from any of my child views, I need to be able to call dismiss()

This seems to be a known bug with SwiftUI, present even in iOS version 17.
To get around it, you can dismiss your views with presentationMode, like this
struct DismissThisView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode

    var body: some View {
        Button("Dismiss!") {
            mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
}


This avoids having to reference the \.dismiss environment variable, which avoids the hanging behavior when trying to use NavigationLinks.
